# find the value of $f(1,2)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Given that the  differential  equation
>
> $f(x,y) \frac {dy}{dx} + x^2 +y = 0$  is exact  and $f(0,y) =y^2$ , then $f(1,2)$ is

choose the  correct  option

$a)$ $5$

$b)$$4$

$c)$ $6$

$d)$ $0$

My attempt :  $(x^2+y)dx -f(x,y) dy =0$  Here $M =(x^2 +y)$  , $N=f(x,y)$

I know  that for exact  $\frac{dM}{dy} = \frac{dN}{dx}$ that is  $f(x,y) =1$

After that im not able to proceed  further

Comment: You did some mistakes during the solution

Comment: @Qurultay okss..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This is the solution, your answer should be option (A).

Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: thanks u @Math is fun

Comment: Most welcome man.

Answer (score 2):

Your equation is $$(x^2+y)dx+f(x,y)dy=0$$
thus from $\frac{dM}{dy}=\frac{dN}{dx}$ we have 
$$\frac{df}{dx}=1$$
or
$$f(x,y)=x+h(y)$$
Now ...

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x,y) \frac {dy}{dx} + x^2 +y = 0$$
$$(x^2+y)dx+fdy=0$$
$$Mdx+Ndy=0$$
$$ {\partial_y} M=\partial_x N $$
$$ \implies 1=\partial_x f$$
After integration we get :
$$f(x,y)=x+g(y)$$
We are given $f(0,y)=y^2$
$$ y^2 =g(y) \implies f(x,y)=x+y^2$$
And 
$$f(1,2)=1+2^2=5$$